# Using Angular with breeze and require

Tags: angularjs, require, breeze

i am trying to use angular with breeze and requireJS
how ever i am getting error of 
Uncaught Error: Module name "ko" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

i have configured

```
define("breezeConfig", ["breeze"], function(breeze) {
// configure to use the model library for Angular
//breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance({ dataService: "OData" });
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);

// configure to use camelCase
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();

var serverAddress = "/odata/";
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serverAddress);
return breeze;
```

});

and in the main module

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "/app",
paths: {
    "jQuery": "lib/jquery-1.8.2",
    "angular": "lib/angular",
    "angular-resource": "lib/angular-resource",
    "text": "lib/text",
    "Q": "lib/q",
    "breeze": "lib/breeze.min"
 and so on
```

at the end

```
require([
'jQuery',
'Q',
'breeze',
'angular',
'app',
'controllers',
'routes',
'breezeConfig'
```

], function ($, angular, app) {

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['AMail']);
});
```

where am i wrong?

Comment: Wild guess, that's indicating something is looking for KnockoutJS. Presumably breeze. `ko` is what KnockoutJS is saved as by default.

Comment: yes but basically you can change the modellibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ... we know. It's been [reported on S.O. before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327347/breeze-requires-knockout-when-use-requirejs). We have a fix on the way (next release).

Meanwhile, inside your main module do two things:

1) define a bogus knockout module

```
define('ko', function() {}); // do nothing
```

2) add a shim to your require.config function:

```
...
shim: {
       jquery: { exports: '$' },
       angular: { exports: 'angular' },
       breeze: { deps: ['ko', 'jquery', 'Q'] }
      }
...
```

You'll need the shim  (***minus the 'ko' dependency!***) even after we fix the ko problem. Breeze depends on 'jquery' and 'Q' which must be loaded first. You may or may not need the other shim lines.